# Identify table and table cells of an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to read data from a data table presented in an image.

Image example:

[image: Scanned image of a data table]

High resolution image is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ZDI.jpg

Currently I have been able to detect and crop the table from the image using opencv (C++). What are the steps I should take to crop cell by cell of the table to later perform OCR ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to try different things, such as:

a) Once you have cropped the table, run a Canny **edge detector** to detect the (well-defined) lines in the image. Do something like:

```
Mat im = imread("zUwozvn.jpg"); //read your image 
Mat gr,edges;
cvtColor(im,gr,CV_BGR2GRAY); // 
imshow("ori",gr);
Canny(gr,edges,50,100); // try different thresholds!
imshow("edges",edges);
waitKey();
```

This is what I obtained:

[image]

Once you have the detected edges, you may want to calculate the vertical and horizontal projections of the edge image (i.e. the sum of pixels in each row and column respectively) to detect your table cells.

b) Instead of the edge detection-based method, try an existing text detection algorithm, such as the one implemented in OpenCV 3.0.0 (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/erfilter.html).

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. i will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: can you please provide the latest URL in your answer